# Does elif must followed by else in python as a common rule?

Tags: python, pep

I wrote some python code like:

```
if platform == 'ios':
    do_something()
elif platform == 'android':
    do_something_else()
```

And this piece of code was strongly criticized by one of my colleague. He accused me why I don't have an else block to handle the rest part.

In my opinion, all I need to do is to deal with these two situations, since I did not write the else block. I meant for else situations, the program will just let it pass through this check and continue going.

Was an else block necessary (obey some PEP rules) for any if elif block?

If it is morally compulsory, should I write my code as:

```
if platform == 'ios':
    do_something()
if platform == 'android':
    do_something_else()
```

But I still feel my first block just OK. Am I wrong?

Comment: Zen, your colleague is wrong.

Comment: It depends on you program logic whether you should handle the `else` case.  If it is an error condition, yes, you should handle it.  If there are simply two cases that require special treatment and the normal case requires no treatment, then no, why bother writing an `else` case.

Comment: You should ask your colleague if they would prefer `else: pass`...

Comment: @SethMMorton, didn't dare to argue with him, he is senior staff and is famous of his bad temper.

Comment: Of course. I was illustrating the ridiculousness of the situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`else` is not required from the syntax point of view and is not enforced by `PEP8`. If you intended do nothing if `platform` is not `ios` or `android` then this is perfectly ok.

Alternatively, you can have a mapping "platform > function", something along these lines:

```
mapping = {'ios': do_something, 'android': do_something_else}
f = mapping.get(platform)
if f:
    f()
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code but in this case either way would've been fine. There was a logical reason that your code needed to be that way and that's fine. You do not have to follow the rules all the time, you have to be able to try different stuff all the time.